Diffeomorphism between $GL_n(\mathbb{R}) \times M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$ and $T GL_n(\mathbb{R})$
I am trying to prove the following corollary:
Let $M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$ denote the real $n \times n$ matrices and $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ let denote the invertible matrices. Then:

$GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ is an open subest of $M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$
For fixed $M \in M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$, the map $L_M:GL_n(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$, $L_M(A):= AM$ defines a vector field on $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$.
The map $(A,M) \mapsto (A,L_M(A))$ defines a diffeomorphism from $GL_n(\mathbb{R}) \times M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$ to $T GL_n(\mathbb{R})$.

About 1:
The idea is to identify $M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$ with $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$. Then since $det: GL_n(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\setminus {0}$ is a surjective map and $\mathbb{R}\setminus {0}$ is open we get that we get that $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ is open.
About 2:
Point 2 boils down, to identifying AM as a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$.
About 3:
I know that I need to show that the map $(A,M) \mapsto (A,L_M(A))$ is bijective, continuously differentiable with continuously differentiable inverse. But I don't know how to do those three things. I would be happy if someone could show me, how to.

You can write down the formula for the map and its inverse. Then you use the formula to prove all three assertions.

What is your definition of the tangent bundle? In order that the map in 3. is well-defined, you need to have $TGL_n(\mathbb R) = GL_n(\mathbb R) \times M_{n \times n}(\mathbb R)$.


:


Then since $\det: GL_n(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\setminus {0}$ is a surjective map and $\mathbb{R}\setminus {0}$ is open we get that we get that $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ is open.

This argument does not make sense. It only shows that $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ is an open subset of itself which is trivial. What you  need is that $\det: M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. Since $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$, it follows that $GL_n(\mathbb{R}) = \det^{-1}(\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\})$ is open in $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$.

and 3.:

As Paul Frost comments, it seems that you regard the tangent bundle of $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ as $GL_n(\mathbb{R}) \times M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$. This is legitimate in this case, but I can't imagine that this is the true definition of the tangent bundle. Anyway, there exists a natural diffeomorphism $\phi : TGL_n(\mathbb{R}) \to GL_n(\mathbb{R}) \times M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$, and this is all we need here.
The map
$$L : GL_n(\mathbb{R}) \times M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R}) \to TGL_n(\mathbb{R}) = GL_n(\mathbb{R}) \times M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R}), L(A,M) = (A, AM) $$
is clearly smooth because matrix multiplication is a polynomial in $2n^2$ variables under the identification $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R}) = \mathbb R^{n^2}$. It also preserves the fibre $\{A\} \times M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ over $A$.
It is well-known that matrix inversion $I : GL_n(\mathbb{R}) \to GL_n(\mathbb{R}), I(A) = A^{-1}$, is smooth. Thus
$$K : GL_n(\mathbb{R}) \times M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R}) \to TGL_n(\mathbb{R}) = GL_n(\mathbb{R}) \times M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R}), K(A,M) = (A,A^{-1}M) $$
is smooth. One has $K \circ L = id$ and $L \circ K = id$, thus $L$ is a diffeomorphism.
The function
$$X_M : GL_n(\mathbb{R})  \to TGL_n(\mathbb{R}) = GL_n(\mathbb{R}) \times M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R}), X_M(A) = L(A,M)$$
is a smooth section of the tangent bundle, that is, a vector field.
